# Satellizer.Js is not sending the Authorization header to the server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, satellizer

Problem: Satellizer is not sending the Authorization Header to server.

I am trying out Satellizer.Js on a project that I am working on.  It's great so far, however, it is not properly sending the Authorization Header in the request to the server (Note: I am using Node for the backend).  It's not a CORS problem, since I'm working with localhost for the time being.  When I locally log in/sign up, the server responds with a token, and Satellizer correctly sets that in local storage. I check the Network tab in the dev tools to check the headers, but no Authorization header.  Has anyone dealt with this, or have any ideas/tips I can use? Thanks in advance.

Here is my server.js code:

```
var express = require('express'),
app = express(),
path = require('path'),
cors = require('cors'),
bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
mongoose = require('mongoose'),
config = require('./config/config'),
morgan = require('morgan'),
port = process.env.PORT || 8080;


var express = require('express'),
app = express(),
path = require('path'),
cors = require('cors'),
bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
mongoose = require('mongoose'),
config = require('./config/config'),
morgan = require('morgan'),
port = process.env.PORT || 8080;


//connect to the database
mongoose.connect(config.db);
//morgan - log all requests to the console
app.use(morgan('dev'));

//middleware for body parser
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//handle CORS requests
app.use(cors());
/*app.use(function(req,res,next){
   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');
   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, content-type, \ Authorization');  
   next();
});*/

//set the location for static files
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

//API Routes
var apiRoutes = require('./app/routes/app-routes.js')(app,express);

app.use('/auth', apiRoutes);

//send the users to the front end
app.get('*', function(req,res){
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/app/views/index.html')); 
});


//listen on port
app.listen(port, function(){
   console.log('Listening on port: ' + port + "...."); 
});
```

Here is where to token gets set on the angular side with satellizer:

```
vm.login = function(){
        $auth.login({email: vm.user.email, password: vm.user.password})
            .then(function(res){                    
                //check for token;
                if(!res.data.token){
                    vm.error = true;
                    vm.errorMessage = res.data.message;
                }else{
                    //redirect to the dashboard

                    $location.path('/dashboard');
                }    
            })
            .catch(function(){
                vm.error = true;
                vm.errorMessage = "Failed to login, please try again."
            });
    };
```

Here is my only authenticated route:

```
router.get('/dashboard', ensureAuthenticated, function(req,res){
    //with a validated token
    console.log(req.headers);
    console.log(req.headers.authorization);
    res.json({success: true, message:'You made it, congrats!'});
});
```

This is my create-a-token function, and this is my authentication middleware:

```
function createToken(user){
    var payload = {
        exp: moment().add(14, 'days').unix,  
        iat: moment().unix(),
        sub: user._id
    }
    return jwt.encode(payload,config.secret);
};

function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
          if (!req.headers.authorization) {
            return res.status(401).send({ message: 'Please make sure your request has an Authorization header' });
          }
          var token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];

          var payload = null;
          try {
            payload = jwt.decode(token, config.secret);
          }
          catch (err) {
            return res.status(401).send({ message: err.message });
          }

          if (payload.exp <= moment().unix()) {
            return res.status(401).send({ message: 'Token has expired' });
          }
          req.user = payload.sub;
          next();
    }
```

Note: Satellizer.Js 's $httpInterceptor is responsible for sending the token in the request.  Here is that code:

```
.factory('SatellizerInterceptor', [
  '$q',
  'SatellizerConfig',
  'SatellizerStorage',
  'SatellizerShared',
  function($q, config, storage, shared) {
    return {
      request: function(request) {
        if (request.skipAuthorization) {
          return request;
        }

        if (shared.isAuthenticated() && config.httpInterceptor(request)) {
          var tokenName = config.tokenPrefix ? config.tokenPrefix + '_' + config.tokenName : config.tokenName;
          var token = storage.get(tokenName);

          if (config.authHeader && config.authToken) {
            token = config.authToken + ' ' + token;
          }

          request.headers[config.authHeader] = token;
        }

        return request;
      },
      responseError: function(response) {
        return $q.reject(response);
      }
    };
  }])
.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('SatellizerInterceptor');
}]);
```

Comment: Post your Angular and Node.js code along with CORS config.  It's very unlikely Satellizer is broken.

Comment: @kyrylkov added my code :)

Comment: So it worked when both Angular code and Node.js app where on localhost?  When deployed remotely, is your Angular app hosted at a different domain from Node.js server?

Comment: @kyrylkov No, it's the same domain .  I haven't remotely deployed it yet; still on localhost.

Comment: If it's the same domain, it has nothing to do with CORS.

Comment: Your Angular Satellizer config is still missing along with relevant Node.js code for `auth` route.  Please expand.

Comment: @kyrylkov the updates have been made

Comment: How did you verify the header isn't being set?  Did you use fiddler to watch the header for the request?

Comment: @kyrylkov I inspected the network in dev tools.  When my middleware runs, it responds with a 401.  In the dev tools, I can see that my request does not contain the authorization header.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the Authorization header like this...

```
request.headers.Authorization = token;
```

Comment: Unfortunatly, explicitly setting the headers isn't working.  Satellizer is supposed to do this on it's own though..

Comment: Did you try my suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

What's your motivation behind setting `token` manually with `$auth.setToken` when `Satellizer` takes care of it automatically when `$auth.login` is used?

Here is `Satellizer` login example which works perfectly in our apps:

```
angular.module('MyApp')
  .controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $location, $auth, toastr) {
    $scope.login = function() {
      $auth.login($scope.user)
        .then(function() {
          toastr.success('You have successfully signed in!');
          $location.path('/');
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          toastr.error(error);
        });
    };
  });
```

Bottom line: you shouldn't set `token` yourself.  `Satellizer` does it automatically behind the scenes.

Comment: I only wish this was the answer.  I set the token there when I was debugging.  :/

Comment: @elloM8 The problem is on your side.  Clone and run `Satellizer` example directory and see if it works like that.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is most definitely on my end.  Cloning and running the repo worked great.  At least I know its not an error with satellizer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. You must send all requests with "/api/" prefix. Without this prefix I got error, but w